# ObjectiveC - determine block return type at compile time

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Would it be possible to determine the return type of a declared block, at compile time? The compiler is doing it, by inferring the type based on the return statements within the block. Is this result available to the programmer too?

For example:

```
^{
    return [NSArray array];
}
```

is translated by the compiler to

```
^NSArray*(){
    return [NSArray array];
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a macro similar to `__typeof__`, but that returns the block return type. For example a macro like `DECLARE_BLOCK(myBlock, ^{return [NSArray array];})` would expand as `NSArray* (^myBlock)() = ^{...}`.

I'd be able to use that macro to allow flexible blocks to be declared, something similar to the `auto` construct in `C++11`.

Comment: It is questions like these that make me wonder why in the world do you need this behavior?  Can you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm curious what you mean here by the compiler "inferring the type based on the return statements within the block." The compiler knows that type it expects (based on the declaration, which you're trying to eliminate), and it *verifies* that the types match. That's different than type inference.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense. What if you have `^id{return @[];}`? It returns an `NSArray*` but its return type is `id`. Pretty sure the compiler considers your example to return an `id` too, btw.

Comment: The compiler can tell the difference between an `id` and `NSArray*` type. It's just the runtime that can't (in the absence of a real object that it can query). The kind of type inference being discussed isn't impossible; it's similar to C++'s `auto`. It just doesn't exist in ObjC.

Comment: Not that I don't agree with @TimReddy. Even if you could figure out how to do this, the end result would be more likely tears than happiness. Macro tricks often create much more trouble than the little bit of typing they avoid.

Comment: @TimReddy: Among other stuff, I need a DECL(varName, block) macro that will expand to BlockResultType var = block();, without manually declaring the type, or casting it later (yeah, I know, I'm a lazy programmer :)

Comment: @Kevin: the block return type is optional in ObjectiveC, if not present then the compiler will try to infer the type by looking at the contents of the block (more exactly at the return statements).

Comment: @Cristik I'm unclear as to the business problem, but if you're trying to avoid littering your code with hairy block definitions, you'd generally do block `typedef`. Does that accomplish what you're trying to do? You can then use that `typedef` for block properties, block parameters, etc.

Comment: @Rob: thanks for the suggestion, however I need a solution to support any kind of declared block. This will be part of a larger macro that will allow me to get automatic variable declaration based on the declared block.

For example 
`DECL(myArray,^{return @[@1,@2,@3];})`
would result in something like
`NSArray(^myArrayBlock)() = ^{return @[@1,@2,@3];
NSArray *myArray = myArrayBlock();`
Ofcourse my macro will be more complicated, I extracted only the part related to the variable type genrated.

Comment: @Cristik Are you trying to actually reimplement the compiler using macros? It looks like it. This is a really bad (and impossible) idea for many reasons.

Comment: @Sulthan I'n trying to reimplement the compiler, I need this type inference only for this case. Since the compiler is able to tell what data type the block returns even if not specified, I was hoping this cant be determined also programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice and simple way to obtain the return type: `__typeof__(^{...}())` - simulate the call of the block.

The solution is not mine, I discovered it on a pull request submitted for the Kiwi framework (https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/pull/528/files).